# Trying to build a calculator in java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, math, calculator

In here im just trying to add first numbers to the second numbers when (=) button is pressed. this code shows only the second number on the screen when (=) button is pressed. once this works i want it to work with different arithmetic operator buttons e.g (+ - * /). please help if you can figure out my code.

private class TheHandler implements ActionListener{

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //add values to buttons
        String num = "";
        if(e.getSource()==btn[0]){
            num = "7";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[1]){
            num = "8";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[2]){
            num = "9";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[5]){
            num = "4";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[6]){
            num = "5";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[7]){
            num = "6";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[10]){
            num = "1";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[11]){
            num = "2";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[12]){
            num = "3";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[15]){               
            num = "0";
        }

        //set the values to the text field          
        if (tDisplay.getText().equals("0"))
            tDisplay.setText(num);
        else
            tDisplay.setText(tDisplay.getText()+num);

        //temporary values to be stored when arithmetic operators are pressed
        double tempValue =0;
        double tempValue2 =0;
        double equalsTo=0;

        //if = button is pressed
        if(e.getSource()==btn[19]){
            tempValue2 = Double.parseDouble(tDisplay.getText());
            equalsTo = tempValue+tempValue2;
            tDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(equalsTo));
        }

        //if + button is pressed
        if(e.getSource()==btn[3]){
            tempValue = Double.parseDouble(tDisplay.getText());
            tDisplay.setText("");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have declared local variables to store your intermediate results, so these variables are reinitialized to 0 each time your action is performed. Instead, you might want them to be class properties, so the values in variables can "survive" several calls to actionPerformed method.

Comment: Your absolutely right that did the job. Now how can i get the calculator to work on different buttons e.g (+ - * /) when the  (=) button is pressed?

Comment: You need one more variable to store current operation (for example, code of operation) that you enter, and then, based on that operation, you would perform correct actions.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(e.getSource()==btn[19]){
     tempValue2 = Double.parseDouble(tDisplay.getText());
     equalsTo = tempValue+tempValue2;
     tDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(equalsTo));
}
```

is doing what you told it to do.

tempValue2 remains 0 because

```
double tempValue =0;
```

so the sum will always be `tempValue2` because `tempValue2 + 0 == tempValue2`

You parseDouble for `tempValue2` but you don't do it for `tempValue`

Comment: yea i know thats what its doing if i dont initialize tempValue to 0 then i get an error 
double tempValue ;

Comment: Yeah but right now the code logic doesn't sum up anything it just displays one of your inputs. There is no summation going on because the other value is always 0. You have to process both inputs and sum them up.